# How to fix the trait `parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `Hash`

Tags: rust, substrate, parity

I am trying to define Substrate runtime-api. I am using substrate master branch for dependencies.

Here is code

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
use codec::Codec;
use codec::{Encode, Decode};


sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
/// The API to verify barcode
pub trait BarcodeScannerApi<Hash> where
    Hash: Codec, {
    /// Verify barcode
    fn is_valid_barcode(barcode: Hash) -> bool;
}
}
```

While building code, I am getting below error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Hash: parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/barcode-scanner/runtime-api/src/lib.rs:6:1
   |
6  | / sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
7  | |     /// The API to verify barcode
8  | |     pub trait BarcodeScannerApi<Hash> where
9  | |         Hash: Codec, {
...  |
12 | |     }
13 | | }
   | |_^ the trait `parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `Hash`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `sp_api::Encode` for `Hash`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `sp_api::Encode` for `&Hash`
   = note: required by `sp_api::Encode::encode`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
9  |         Hash: Codec + parity_scale_codec::codec::WrapperTypeEncode, {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Did you try following the suggestion in the error message? `help: consider further restricting this bound`